# Syntax error while creating SQLite Table Android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to use foreign key for two tables, now my code as below I am getting syntax error. Please solve this error. Thanks in advance

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DB_TABLE+" ("+
                        KEY_TBNAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);"

        );
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE_CATE + " (" +
                KEY_DETAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_AMOUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_RESOURCE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                        KEY_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                       "FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_TB_CATE+") REFERENCES "+DB_TABLE+" ("+KEY_TBNAME+");");

    }
```

Error...

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.burhani.quickaccount/app.burhani.quickaccount.HomeActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ";": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE tablenamecate (detail TEXT NOT NULL, amount INTEGER NOT NULL, resource TEXT NOT NULL, date TEXT NOT NULL, time TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (tbnameis) REFERENCES tablename (tbname);

Comment: can u plz post complete query?

Comment: And the "syntax error"?

Comment: I Edited Error . Please see it

Comment: That's still not the complete query. Either post all of it (including your contract fields), or log the output and post that.

Comment: nope , i need to see the complete query...from query i could not undesrtand what is it slect update ???ect

Comment: I edited full query. Please solve, Thanks in Advance @diva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be real query :

```
CREATE TABLE DB_TABLE (  KEY_TBNAME  TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE  DB_TABLE_CATE  (
                KEY_DETAIL  TEXT NOT NULL,
                        KEY_AMOUNT  INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                        KEY_RESOURCE  TEXT NOT NULL, 
                        KEY_DATE  TEXT NOT NULL, 
                        KEY_TIME  TEXT NOT NULL,
                        KEY_TBNAME TEXT NOT NULL,
                       FOREIGN KEY(KEY_TBNAME) REFERENCES  DB_TABLE(KEY_TBNAME));
```

You have to define KEY_TBNAME and then set foreign key.
I could run this query in sqlite browser and it worked for me

Comment: error show me again. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.burhani.quickaccount/app.burhani.quickaccount.HomeActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown column "tbname" in foreign key definition (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE tablenamecate (detail TEXT NOT NULL, amount INTEGER NOT NULL, resource TEXT NOT NULL, date TEXT NOT NULL, time TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (tbname) REFERENCES tablename (tbname));

Comment: Thanks, I just forget creating column TBNAME

Answer (score 1):

You get `near ";": syntax error` because you need two closing parentheses, one for the FK column name list, and one for the table column list:

```
... REFERENCES  DB_TABLE(KEY_TBNAME));
```

You have another error: the column KEY_TB_CATE in the FK must *also* appear in the column list.

Comment: Error give me again. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.burhani.quickaccount/app.burhani.quickaccount.HomeActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown column "tbname" in foreign key definition (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE tablenamecate (detail TEXT NOT NULL, amount INTEGER NOT NULL, resource TEXT NOT NULL, date TEXT NOT NULL, time TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (tbname) REFERENCES tablename (tbname));

Comment: Thanks i just forget creat column KEY_TBNAME